# how to get the current google resource price programmatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I want to get the Pricing for Google cloud resources programatically and all the documents and references I see only takes me to the https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api. This page lists just 2 apis, one to give a list of all services and other to give the SKUs under that service.
Are there no other refined apis that can give me only the details I want ? like pricing for Compute engine in a region ?
Do I need to query these huge json files just to get the price of one resource ?

Also is there a static look up value for these service display names ? like "Compute Engine" how do I know what are all the names google uses for say App Engine, or Cloud Storage etc ?

Comment: Please let me know, if you was able to find the answer. I have exactly the same scenario as you have described in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This allows developers to manage billing for their Google Cloud Platform projects [programmatically](https://github.com/googleapis/python-billing). There is a very old [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/35900616) on this issue as Feature Request. Feel free to post there for further updates and also put your current requirement.